# Regular Expression for Technical Words - C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am Parsing Employee's resume and displaying in text boxes with respective field(Name, Email, Mobile Number) this is done like each word comparing with regular expression Email, Name, Mobile Number. I want to get the Employee's technical skills like C#.net, Asp.net,WCF .. etc., from his resume.

How can I compare and get the technical words by assuming employee  written as his skills in his resume like  word1,word2,.......etc.,

Is there any regular expression for that?? or Is it possible to get that? Please help me anyone?

Comment: Paste an example please

Answer (score 3):

Regex don't apply with this scenario.

You look like being intersted in **keyword** analysis. Regex are designed to find textual patterns, like recognizing a phone number from a +\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d string (so that wherever you type +1-555-2025 you get the phone number). The same for emails, and that's exactly how spammers harvest email addresses shattered across the web.

You won't be able to use regex for matching skills. Rather create a database of common skills and search them among the text. You'll also find that some candidates might write "VB.NET" or "VB dot net" etc.

Comment: How it is possible to find "VB.Net or VB dotnet" terms?

Comment: I said: create a dictionary of common words, then match the text for them

Answer (score 0):

Why not save in a skills database, using an array of common different words for each skill, and find out in each comparison if exists or not. If not, just add it.
The code will look like with simple strings comparison.

Answer (score 0):

if you just looking for the comma-seperated values you can do:

```
IEnumerable<string> skills = resume.split(',').Select(skill=> skill.Trim());
```